# Getting spinny and some extra delay during my Selenium Specflow tests in Visual Studio 17

Tags: visual-studio, mstest, specrun

I upgraded to Specrun 1.7.1, and I have Specflow 2.3.0.  One thing I noticed this after the upgrade, I am getting this extra spinny icon adjacent to a test when I run a single test in VS Test Explorer.  I also noticed that this same icon next to the test will turn into some sort of clock icon when running an entire suite.  I am not sure what this means, but looks like it introduced some latency before running the tests.  Is this part of the new upgrade? Is this VS related? Is this something I need to worry about? If so, how do I fix and remove this from happening?

[image: Spinny running during tests]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The new icons & animations are from the Visual Studio 2017 15.7 Update (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes#test)

They shouldn't add any latency when you are starting a test.